# Why does this simple bash code give a syntax error?

Tags: bash, syntax-error

I have the following bash code, which is copied and pasted from "bash cookbook" (1st edition):

```
#!/bin/bash

VERBOSE=0;
if [[ $1 =-v ]]
then
    VERBOSE=1;
    shift;
fi
```

When I run this (bash 4.0.33), I get the following syntax error:

```
./test.sh: line 4: conditional binary operator expected
./test.sh: line 4: syntax error near `=-v'
./test.sh: line 4: `if [[ $1 =-v ]]'
```

Is this as simple as a misprint in the bash cookbook, or is there a version incompatibility or something else here? What would the most obvious fix be? I've tried various combinations of changing the operator, but I'm not really familiar with bash scripting.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Bash uses spaces to tokenise scripts. The line:

```
if [[ $1 =-v ]]
```

should be:

```
if [[ $1 = -v ]]
```

Comment: I could have sworn I'd tried that, but obviously not. Thanks.